# Adding tooltip to Kendo Toolbar buttons

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Toolbar with some buttons, all of the buttons have Images and I don't use text in them. How can I add `tooltip`, or `alt` text to them?

Is Kendo Tooltip the only solution?

```
@(Html.Kendo().ToolBar()
    .Name("toolbar")
    .Items(items =>
    {
        items.Add().Type(CommandType.Button).Text(" ").Click("").ImageUrl("/Content/Images/Icon/Add.png");
...
```

If I use a template to use the image, as suggested by @rozerocool. I'll loose the button style. See the below picture, the right one is using a template and the left one is using `ImageUrl`.

[image]

**UPDATE**

as @rozerocool suggested, I'm using `template`.

```
items.Add().Template("<img src='" + Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Icon/Add.png") + "' alt='add image' title='Add image tooltip' />");
```

It doesn't render as a button, therefore it's not clickable. Unless I add some classes to it:

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-button k-button-icon" })
```

With these classes, It'll be a clickable button, but still it doesn't function and I'll get error when clicking it.

It [seems](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/toolbar#configuration-items.template) that `template` isn't really useful in this case.

> Specifies what element will be added in the ToolBar wrapper. Items with template does not have a type.

Comment: Is it an option to give an `id` to each item? If so, you can use Kendo tooltips

Answer (score 4):

As @chiapa suggested you can simply use an id and Kendo Tooltips:

```
// Toolbar with button
$('#toolbar').kendoToolBar({
   items: [
      { type: "button", text: "MyButton", id: "btn_mybutton" }
   ]
});

// The Tooltip
$('#btn_mybutton').kendoTooltip({
    position: "bottom",
    content: "Here is the TT-Text"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your button like this:

```
items.Add().Template("<img src='" + 
Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Icon/Add.png") + 
"' alt='add image' title='Add image tooltip' />");
```

You can find more about Kendo Toolbar in [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/toolbar/index).

Comment: Thanks for your replay, this does the job for sure, but can I keep the button's style as well? Take a look at the picture in updated question.

Comment: I'm sure you can. Inspect the original Kendo button and copy it's styles. It may include having a different structure (eg: a parent div to your img tag).

Comment: There is another thing too, the button doesn't work when using a custom template! Have you tried it yourself, there's something wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you please expand? It's hard to tell what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

As of now (from Q2 2014) you can  add `attributes: { title: "any tooltip" }`

if you want kendo's Tool tip

just do

```
$(".k-toolbar [title]").kendoTooltip({
    position:"top"
});
```

Full code would look like this

```
$("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({
    items: [
        { type: "button", text: "MyButton", id: "myButton", attributes: { title: "my tool tip" }  },
        { type: "button", text: "Toggle Button", togglable: true },
        { type: "separator" }
    ]
});
$(".k-toolbar [title]").kendoTooltip({
    position:"top"
});
```